# Dialog is not modal when ProgressDialog and Dialog are opened in sequence

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm running wxPython 4.0.1 msw (phoenix) with Python 3.6.5 on a Windows7 machine, as well as wxPython 2.9.4 with Python 2.7.

I'm observing an issue with a modal dialog, which doesn't block the access to its parent window behind. This only occurs if I run a progress dialog followed by a modal dialog. This behavior is somehow related to custom dialogs. Integrated dialogs like wx.MessageDialog doesn't seem to have this issue.

To isolate the issue, I've written an example. The first two buttons open either the progress or the modal dialog and work properly. The third button opens both dialogs in sequence. In this case the modal functionality of the custom dialog doesn't work and I'm able to access and close the mainframe. Which causes multiple issues.

[Dialog is not modal, the main window can be accessed and closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Eraw.png)

```
import wx    

class SomeDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title='SomeDialog',
                           style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)
        self.button_ok = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, size=(120,-1))
        hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hsizer.Add(self.button_ok, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 10)
        self.SetSizer(hsizer)
        self.SetSize(self.BestSize)
        self.Layout()

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, size=(400, 400))
        self.button_progress = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Show Progress')
        self.button_modal = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Show Modal')
        self.button_both = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Show Both')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button, self.button_progress)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button, self.button_modal)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button, self.button_both)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.button_progress)
        sizer.Add(self.button_modal)
        sizer.Add(self.button_both)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def on_button(self, event):
        if event.EventObject is self.button_progress:
            self._show_progress_dialog()
        elif event.EventObject is self.button_modal:
            self._show_modal_dialog()
        else:
            self._show_progress_dialog()
            self._show_modal_dialog()

    def _show_progress_dialog(self):
        max = 10
        dlg = wx.ProgressDialog('Progress dialog example', 'Some message',
                                maximum=max, parent=self, 
                                style=wx.PD_APP_MODAL|wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE)
        keepGoing = True
        count = 0
        while keepGoing and count < max:
            count += 1
            wx.MilliSleep(250)
            wx.Yield()
            (keepGoing, skip) = dlg.Update(count)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def _show_modal_dialog(self):
        with SomeDialog(self) as dlg:
            dlg.CenterOnParent()
            dlg.ShowModal()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

In case this is an issue in the wxpython framework and not an issue with my implementation, it would be great if someone could provide me a workaround to show such dialogs in sequence.

Comment: Perhaps it is a windows issue. On linux, whilst it looks as if I can close the main frame, I can't.

Comment: I can confirm the issue exists on windows 10, python 3.6, phoenix 4.0.4a1

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me. I'm not sure why its happening, but one workaround would be to use [wx.CallLater](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.CallLater.html)

changing `_show_modal_dialog` to:

```
def _show_modal_dialog(self):
    def _make_dialog():
        with SomeDialog(self) as dlg:
            dlg.CenterOnParent()
            dlg.ShowModal()

    wx.CallLater(50, _make_dialog) # 50 mils is arbitrary
```

Seems to resolve the issue of the dialog not acting modalish. The problem with this workaround is that it will be non-blocking, meaning that any code that has to wait for the dialog to return has to be moved into the dialog class or passed to the dialog as a callback.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation that this bug also occurs in the latest version of wxpython and Windows 10. 
The workaround you provided is unfortunately not applicable or practical for me, since it changes the sequence of actions. The program flow expects some changes to the applications state after _show_modal_dialog() is called. The CallLater will delay this change and is no longer blocking the following program flow. Of course I could fix this, triggering some events to notify about the change but I would like to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a workaround myself which I like to share.

I added a handler catching the windows close event.

```
class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        #...
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)
```

This event function checks if some child dialog is open and modal and performs a veto.

```
def on_close(self, event):
    # In case any modal dialog is open, prevent the frame from closing.
    for children in (c for c in self.Children if isinstance(c, wx.Dialog)):
        if children.IsModal():
            event.Veto()
            return
    event.Skip()
```

This is also only a workaround, but I seems to work for my use cases.